# A step in the proof of the analytic continuation of $ \zeta $

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence, riemann-zeta

I'm reading *The Theory of Riemann zeta function*, in the process of proving the analytic continuation we proved using Fourrier Series :

$$ [x] - x + \frac{1}{2} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin2n \pi x}{n\pi}$$

We write  $s=\sigma + it $,  for $-1<\sigma<0$ , we have also proved by *Abel summation* that :
$$ \zeta(s) = s \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{[x] - x + \frac{1}{2}}{x^{s + 1}}dx $$ 
By replacing the Fourrier Serie in the integral, we had :
$$ \zeta(s) = s \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin2n \pi x}{n\pi}}{x^{s + 1}}dx =  \frac{s}{\pi} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin 2n\pi x}{x^{s + 1}}dx $$
**My Problem :** I don't understand why we can permute between the integral and the sum. The book says

"We have still to justify the term-by-term integration. Since the 
series ( it referred to the Fourrier Serie above) is boundedly convergent, term-by-term integration over 
any finite range is permissible. It is therefore sufficient to prove that

$$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty } \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{\lambda}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (2n\pi x)}{x^{s + 1}} = 0$$

I read *A Course In Calculus and Real Analysis*, I couldn't find a justification. Instead I tried to apply a result in the book where the conditions where $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_k $ is uniformly convergent, neither the fact $ \mid \sum_{k=1}^{n} f_k \mid \leq G $
 where G is a function that it proper integral is convergent. And would yield to : $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \int_{\lambda}^{\infty} f_n = \int_{\lambda}^{\infty} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} f_n   $. If i'm not mistaken $f_k = \frac{\sin 2k\pi x}{x^{s+1}}$.

Thank You For Reading .

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem allows switching integrals and series for bounded convergence as constants are integrable on finite intervals